# Developing view controllers deep in the navigation hierarchy

Tags: ios

I'm wondering how other people approach the problem of working on a particular screen in an iOS app that is, for example, behind a login screen and requires a lot of interaction to navigate too. It can make the development process quite long and tedious. Every time I tweak a part of the UI I must then build and run, login, navigate to the screen, check the result, then repeat until it is correct.

One approach is to add temporary code to the app delegate that sets the view controller currently being worked on as the root view controller of the window, then deleting this code once development of the view controller is complete.

However I feel like others may have a more effective approach than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle to follow is to rely on the User Interface surface (UI) only for data input, and to push as much functionality as possible out of the UI into non-UI classes so that they can be [automation-tested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation) independently of the UI.

[Architectural patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern) such as [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) facilitate this process by providing a sensible structural framework to enforce the necessary [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  More specifically, they [separate content from presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Following these principles reduces your UI testing to simply verifying that the proper data is passed to your underlying classes.